# can anyone help me, why I am getting food is not defined error ? I have attached the structure of Django module

Tags: python, django

[image]

I have added food app. inside food app i added url.py. TO import food.url.py i used include method to import food.url.py in mysite.url.py. but while running the server i am getting error as food is not defined

Comment: Please don't use images of your code. Instead copy and paste your code into your question. It's easier for people to give answers if your question is created that way.

Comment: Add your app *food* in installed apps.

Answer (score 3):

Pass argument in strings of include function like need not be import your apps

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
path('', include('food.urls')), #change in this line 
]
```

In this URLs pattern pass argument in include method as string like include ('food.urls')

In this file not need the import a food apps but see the your import statment syntax is wrong if you use this way python interpreter will find `__init__.py` file in module so create please refer documention of python module or see the following [enter link description here](https://www.javatpoint.com/python-modules)

Answer (score 3):

you does not require to add `from mysite import food`

just add `path('', include('food.urls')` where `food.urls` in single quotation

Make sure `food` app added in your **INSTALLED_APPS** list in `settings.py`

Answer (score 3):

In above file first of all you don't need to add **from mysite import food**
And in your url_patterns the second urls is giving like this:

```
 path('',include('food.urls'))
```

just add one single quotes..